# Creating images from time series features during graph execution using Tensorflow tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord, conv-neural-network

**Setup**

The data are one dimensional time series data. A sliding window (frame) runs across the data and extracts a 100 dimensional vector of features f_{i}( t_{j} ), where i is a file index, and j is the time index of the frame. Energies from n consecutive frames are stacked to form a 2D "image", which is the input to the classifier.

**Basic Approach**

Just save the stacked vectors in a tfrecords file and you are good to go. The drawback is that the stacked vectors have a lot of duplicate data and consume a lot of space. If the we have 10 gigs of feature vectors, then stacking 10 frames of history would require 50 gigs (+ overhead) of space. However, we can let tf.data do the shuffling, prefetching, batch creation and what not. Very convenient!

**Desired Approach**

A implementation where we save only the feature vectors as a tfrecords file, and create the stacked feature vector (images) on the fly.

**Question**

Has this been encountered and dealt with before? Would most people just not care about the high level of repetition in their data or the amount of space consumed?

How difficult is it to get the desired implementation. Even naively shuffling the data would mess up the time ordering. I've also only used tf.data in a way where I call iterator.get_next() to get the feature and label form one example, and then give it to the graph. I suppose I'd also need to figure out how to get not only the current example's feat and label, but also those of it's predecessors in time! So I'm looking for some tips on how to accomplish this.

Here is an image of the process for images formed from 2 frames of feature vectors. Note that in this case, each feature vector would appear twice in the tfrecords data file :

[image]